# Зависимые select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

имею обычный select к которому применен select2

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".program").select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="programm">
  <option value="0">Programm</option>
  <option value="1">Programm1</option>
  <option value="2">Programm2</option>
</select>
```

Требуется:

- создавать дополнительные select(с таким же набором option).
- максимальное количество дополнительных select равняется количеству option первого
- в последующих select option которые выбраны в ранее созданных select не активны.
- при отмене выбора у любого select(или удалении) освободившийся option становится  доступным в оставшихся select

Подскажите куда копать.

Answer (score 0):

Копать сюда =>

- Нужно клонировать элементы 
  https://ruseller.com/jquery?id=23
- Узнать количество options

```js
$('#example option').length
```

- Деактивировать options, ниже абстрактный пример

```js
$('select').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).siblings('select').children('option').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() === value ) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true).siblings().removeAttr('disabled');   
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: СПАСИБО!   КОПАЮ СПАСИБО!   КОПАЮ

Comment: если ответ нужную информацию, можно отметить его верным или нажать на стрелку вверх

Comment: стрелку нажимал но пишет мало репутации.Может еще подскажите:
 select ищу внутри родительского элемента.
`var izi = $(e.target).siblings('div.trigger_box'),` - родитель
`select = $(izi).find('select.programm');` - объект с нужным мне select
0-й элемент нужный мне select. 
мне нужно внутрь izi добавить div с копией select внутри. пробовал так:  
`select2 = $(select[0]).clone(true);
var trigger ="<div class='p-md-box trigger' ><div class='p-md-12'>" +select2+"</div></div>";
$(izi).append(trigger);` - вывожу на страницу
div выводится а вот внутри [object Object]